# Selecting an image from a page to add to another page - WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

i've being searching the net and this forum for a couple of days, but still haven't find an answer to my problem.

Here's the deal: i'm building an wp7 app and i created 2 pages; the first with a grid and some buttons on it; and the second will have a canvas and a ink color selector, where the user can drawn on a white space. I created a NavigationService for the user to click on the button and navigate to the second page.
But now i want that, when the user clicks on this button, a specific image will be loaded on the navigated page, so the user can paint over it, in a canvas.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to have a image inside a Canvas?

```
<Canvas>
    <Image Source="myimage.jpg" Width="100" Height="100" />
</Canvas>
```

Comment: yes, but i need that the image inside the canvas is determined by the button clicked in the first page.

Comment: And? You obviously need to pass a identifier then. And use that identifier to data-bind the image.

Comment: Great, so how do i do that? If you could explain or give me some points, i'll be very thankful!